# How to add a Camera button into a UITabBar?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

Does anyone know how to add a Camera button into a UITabBar, like the one we see in 'Path'?
http://i.appsafari.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/path.jpg

Is it a extended UITabBar/UITabBarItem or an original class?
Please let me know if you have any idea.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would bet it's a custom button floating on top of a "dummy" tab bar item. That's the first approach I'd try to implementing something like that, anyway.

Comment: Sometimes the simple approach is best, eh? Good luck.

Comment: How do you make a "dummy" tab bar item?

Comment: @Tony - Just put something there as a placeholder that you're not going to use. No big trick to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this open source tab bar
https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/RaisedCenterTabBar

Answer (score 0):

@Taketo Sano one alternative to your problem is to give a custom image of camera like button (as you had given) to the tab bar